# Can you find the logical size of a single NotesDocument in a DAOS-enabled database or an uploaded file size?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages

I'm doing some feasability for an XPages application. One of the aspects is checking the amount of space used by users.

The database will be DAOS-enabled to minimise the size of the NSF. Is it possible to identify the logical size of a NotesDocuemnt that has a DAOSed attachment? I know I can find the logical size of the overall database, but need to identify it based on users.

LotusScript or Java would be acceptable options.

The other option is to capture file sizes at upload time and store that information against the user. Is it possible to identify the attachment size at the point of upload and deletion? This would need to be captured before the attachment was moved to the DAOS store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paul,

As far as I know from the client point of view he can't see if a Database/Document has been DAOS'ed or not. SO this meahs that using LotusScript against the document would report the document size as if the attachment(s) would be in the document. I haven't tested it myself to give you a 100% guarantee but you could test it for yourself very easily by enabling a database for DAOS and then create 10 docs with all of them the exact same attachment attached to the documents. If the docs report a size of arround the attachment size when accessed via LotusScript you will have your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You could check the logical size of the database before and after saving the document. But unfortunately, you would have to rig the critical section of this code with a semaphore or some other mechanism that assures that only one instance can run at a time, otherwise two simultaneous saves would give you bad results.

Answer (score 0):

Build a view with a column whose formulas is **@DocLength** or **@Sum(@AttachmentLengths)** This will show the logical size of the docs as if DAOS was not active.

/Newbs